# Select distinct column and get count of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the [following sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4c712/3):

```
CREATE TABLE tester(
  name TEXT,
  address TEXT
 )
```

Each person in the table can have multiple addresses. I'd like to select all names and the number of addresses they have that have > 1 address. I have tried:

```
SELECT d.name, count(address) c FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) FROM tester) d
  LEFT JOIN tester ON d.name = links.name
  WHERE count(address) > 1
```

I get:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM" Position: 64
```

I've also tried a DISTINCT ON query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) name, count(address) FROM tester HAVING count(address) > 1
```

I get:

```
ERROR: column "tester.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 26
```

I feel like I'm making this too difficult.

Comment: Please don't change the nature of the question after answers have been given. Ask a new question instead. I have rolled back edits to your original question.

Comment: you're right. I'll open a new one. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, count(address)
FROM tester
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(address) > 1
```

`GROUP BY` in SQL (as well as in other languages) will always produce distinct groups, so there is no need for `DISTINCT` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use group by correctly.  Like this:

```
SELECT name, count(*) 
FROM tester
group by name
```